A few potential race conditions with signals and PIDs
I'm aware that because of PID-reuse on Unix-like kernels, signals can be delivered to the wrong process if they are sent after the PID has already been reaped.
Discussion of what follows will probably necessarily depend on the specific kernel we're discussing, so I'm happy to reduce scope to Linux. Though I welcome answers with experts on other kernels.
A few situations to consider:

Let's say I'm in the middle of a call to kill(2) to a zombie process (i.e., I'm already in kernel space and executing kernel code to initiate the signal). Concurrently, the parent of the zombie calls wait(2). Is it possible that my call to kill(2) could end up attempting to act on a different process?

Let's say I've kill(2)-ed (i.e., successfully returned into user space from the call) a process, but before my signal can be delivered, a different signal is caught and kills the process. In this case, I assume it's guaranteed that my signal will be trashed? One line of reasoning why is: even if the PID gets reaped and a different process with the same PID is spawned concurrently, delivering the signal to the new process could open permission loopholes.


Thank you

Probably you should write and do yourself tests. I'm not sure interface is so good documented on all details (also not to hinder improvements). In any case, I think kernel deliver immediately the signal to the task/process structure (which will be processed later, but assigned to the "right" process). OTOH with different cores, locks may be delayed. I think the topic is very complex (but I'm curious on answers)

I could write tests, but it seems difficult without digging into kernel code and maybe running it under a debugger. I'm not familiar enough with the kernel for that to be the first strategy I try :)

It doesn't matter, and you write just user space code, to try to find the vulnerabilities. No need to read kernel (it would not help: tests are better: you may miss some code), nor the debugger. Run programs millions of time (it take short time), and check. You want to check if user space can have such race, so just do the race millions of times. (many vulnerabilities are explored in such way: you repeat until timing (or stack, or memory allocator) align. It may take few minutes


Let's say I'm in the middle of a call to kill(2) to a zombie process (i.e., I'm already in kernel space and executing kernel code to initiate the signal). Concurrently, the parent of the zombie calls wait(2). Is it possible that my call to kill(2) could end up attempting to act on a different process?

Yes. There can be an arbitrary amount of time between a process issuing the kill system call, and the point where the kernel decides which process to kill. Some of that time is spent in the process preparing the system call, and some of that time is spent in the kernel. At any point in that processing, the kernel may decide to switch to the execution of some other thread (either due to an interrupt or because the kernel tried to take a lock that's already taken). The process running kill and the process running wait may have the system calls taken by different processors, so they may even be both in kernel mode at the same time.
The kill system call doesn't have a lot to do, so an interruption is not very likely. But it can happen, and it will happen if you try enough times. And on a multiprocessor system, a race is more likely.
You can look at how the Linux kernel handles a system call by looking at the source code. Elixir provides a convenient online viewer with cross-references. The implementation of the kill signal starts with SYSCALL_DEFINE2(kill, …) (the 2 is because there are two parameters). As you can see, the code consists of the very short function prepare_kill_siginfo then the beginning of the function kill_something_info up to the point where that function calls read_lock(&tasklist_lock). Once that call returns, no entry can be added to or removed from the process table, and in particular the entry for pid keeps designating the same process, until the corresponding call to read_unlock just before the function returns. That only leaves a very short time for interrupts to happen or for other processors to acquire the task list lock first, but that time is not and cannot be zero.
Some kernels such as OpenBSD prevent a PID from being reused shortly after the process object is destroyed. That makes the race condition less likely, possibly even impossible if the system is lightly loaded (if it's just you on your PC doing nothing much other than trying to race two processes). But the race condition remains possible if the system is sufficiently loaded (with lots of processes being created and killed). There is no way to prevent the race.
Because of the potential for a race, the design of a multi-process software should generally arrange for processes to be managed by their parent, or at least by their group leader. The parent can make sure that it never tries to kill a process that it's already waited on.

Let's say I've kill(2)-ed (i.e., successfully returned into user space from the call) a process, but before my signal can be delivered, a different signal is caught and kills the process. In this case, I assume it's guaranteed that my signal will be trashed?

Yes, once your process has returned from the kill system call, the kernel has decided which process (or zombie process) the signal is targeting. It's possible that the signal hasn't been processed yet, and the signal will never be delivered if the target is already a zombie. But the kernel chooses which process table entry the signal is for during the execution of the system call.

Thank you. I haven't processed all the details yet, but this does seem like it answers the question. And thank you for the Elixir link!
